# Do I use $P(y_t|y_{1:t-1})$ instead of $P(y_t|z_{t},y_{1:t-1})$ for prediction in a Hidden Markov Model?

Tags: bayesian, sampling, predictive-models, inference, hidden-markov-model

I am confused what to sample for getting the prediction $y_{t}$ if I have access to the previous observations $y_{1:t-1}$ and the hidden states $z_{1:t}$.

I want to predict the observation at time $t$ but I  don't know the standard way of doing this in a HMM.

---

The distributions in the question express different predictions since by the Markov property $$
P(y_t|z_t,y_{t-1})=P(y_t|z_t)
$$ so this distribution only depends on the present hidden state and it does not feel like a "proper" prediction at all.

Meanwhile,$$
P(y_t|y_{1:t-1})=\sum P(y_t|z_t)P(z_t|y_{1:t-1})
$$ feels more "proper" since it is conditioned on all the previous observations but this quantity is the normalisation constant of $P(z_t|y_{1:t})$.

I'm confused on how to correctly get the predictions if I have a HMM with the learned initial, transition and observation distribution,

Comment: Note that the state isn't hidden if you know what it is for the period for which you are making a prediction and for all previous periods.

Comment: @jbowman I "know" them (the prediction period) by sampling from $P(z_t|z_{t-1})$. I don't know if my next step would be to sample from $P(y_t|z_t=k)$ or $P(y_t|y_{1:t-1})$ if I want to know the prediction $y_t$

Comment: I also don't know if it is correct to first sample the state for the prediction period $z_t$

Comment: Are you trying to *predict* or to generate a random sample from $y_t$?

Comment: I am trying to predict $y_t$ @jbowman